# Clean application memory in swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, memory-management

I've an XCode project programmed in swift with a registration/connection process. When you're connected, even if the app restarted you don't repeat this process until you click on "log out" button.

I've noticed that if you follow the registration/connection process when you start the app, **memory is about 500Mb** whereas if the app started with a connected user, **memory is about 140Mb**.

Registration process is composed of 3 view controllers connected with custom segue. Access to logged in view is made by following code :

```
func switchRootViewController(rootViewController: UIViewController, animated: Bool, completion: (() -> Void)?)
    {
        if animated
        {
            UIView.transitionWithView(window!, duration: 0.5, options: .TransitionCrossDissolve, animations:
                {
                let oldState: Bool = UIView.areAnimationsEnabled()
                UIView.setAnimationsEnabled(false)
                self.window!.rootViewController = rootViewController
                UIView.setAnimationsEnabled(oldState)
                }, completion: { (finished: Bool) -> () in
                    if (completion != nil)
                    {
                        completion!()
                    }
            })
        }
        else
        {
            window!.rootViewController = rootViewController
        }
    }
```

Where rootViewController is replace by the logged in view I want to load as you can see here :

```
func goToNextView()
    {
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let homeViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("conversationViewController") as!ConversationViewController
        homeViewController.currentUser = self.currentUser
        let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
        appDelegate.switchRootViewController(home, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

However it doesn't clean the memory.

Here a screen of memory allocation :

[image]

So my question is : **is it possible to "kill" some view controller in order to clean the memory ?**

Here for example it can be obvious to "kill" registration process views when you're connected.

Thank you for answers.

Comment: How are you moving from the registration view controllers to the logged in view controller? You can reset the root view controller for your window and then as long as there aren't any other references to the registration view controllers they will be released

Comment: I've edit my question to answer to your question. I change the root view but it doesn't clean the memory.

Comment: This is such a complex question with so many potential answers that the best thing to do is profile your app. You can profile it by holding down the "Run" button in Xcode and choosing "Profile". There is a memory allocation option there. You should be able to see what it is that is taking up that memory. Essentially the problem is that you are holding onto a reference to something in memory and not allowing it to be released (setting it to nil) etc...

Comment: The class / struct that contains this `switchRootViewController` method. Does that have a stored property of the login view controller?

Comment: I've tried your profile option. Then I've edited my post with a screen of memory allocation when memory is maximum. 
Everytime I switch to the login view controller I instantiate one and then call the 'switchRootViewController' method. 
I've update previous post to be more precise about this switch method.

Comment: This is not how memory management in swift works. Since it is reference-counted, make sure there are no strong references to objects you want to be deallocated. In your case, this might mean that something has a strong reference to your view controller, so that it cannot be 'killed'.

Comment: Such as variable or something like that ?

Comment: Now I'm looking at my controllers and I'm surprised when I see that home controller which does not contain any variable seems to remain in memory. 
It's like a view stack even if I doesn't need anything on the controller. Can you give me an example of strong reference to a view controller ?